# How Dynamics CRM Ribbon changes are merged from multiple solutions

Tags: dynamics-crm, ribbon, dynamics-crm-2015

We have two development teams working on seperate modules of the dynamics crm in different solutions, team A develops customizations in solution A, exports a managed Solution A, this managed solution will be imported on team B's dynamics development organization on regular basis, team B also develops customizations in unmanaged solution B and exports it as a managed solution when it will be given to customer.

When everything is ready Customer can either import only managed solution A or  managed solution B on top of managed solution A.

But Both solution A and solution B includes changes to the ribbons. I am wondering how these changes are merged. Because in the above scenario team A's managed solution is imported into the development environment of team B. At this point Team B might have some unmanaged changes to the ribbon as well.

I am wondering how does dynamics CRM merges these changes. And I am wondering if there can be a case where changes in solution A can be overwritten by Solution B. Even though they are completely mutually exclusive.

From what I deduce from customizations.xml, when I import a managed solution, I don't see any ribbon changes related to that solution in the customizations.xml any more when I just export an unmanaged solution that only contains application ribbon. Which makes me think that when I import a managed solution, those changes in the managed solution are merged into the application ribbon.

Any information would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I've researched, entity ribbon changes are shipped along entities and they are merged automatically. Global Application ribbon and custom group changes are shipped under client extensions in the solution, as far as I've researched they are also automatically merged when to managed solutions are imported one after another.